# Homogenous Linear ODE from standard to normal form. Justification.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have this ODE,

I am going from standard form

1. $$p(x) y'(x)+Q(x) y(x)+y''(x)=0$$

to normal form:

2. $$q(x) u(x)+u''(x)$$

**Question 1** Now it is this way of defining y(x) that I do not get. Can I define it as anything, how did they come up with defining y(x) this way and why?

$$y(x)=u(x) v(x)$$

$$\frac{dy(x)}{dx}=v(x) u'(x)+u(x) v'(x)$$

$$\frac{d^2y(x)}{dx^2}=v(x) u''(x)+2 u'(x) v'(x)+u(x) v''(x)$$

Putting this back into 1 and collecting we get:

3. $$u(x) \left(p(x) v'(x)+Q(x) v(x)+v''(x)\right)+u'(x) \left(p(x)
       v(x)+2 v'(x)\right)+v(x) u''(x)$$

taking the coefficient of u'(x) and setting it equal to zero we , and solving we it we get:

$$v(x)=e^{\int -\frac{p(x)}{2} \, dx}$$

Setting this coefficient equal to zero, reduces 3. and when swapping back in v(x) we are left with 2. where

$$q(x)=- (1/2)p'(x)-(1/4)p(x)^2+Q(x)$$

**Question 2** How can one justify setting a coefficient equal to zero and solving. I have to understand the underlying reason why this would not change the entire equation. I can see that setting it equal to zero and solving means that I get for all x a positive coefficient and that is the only justification I can get, but I still do not get why we can take the coeficient differential equation and just setting it to zero.